# Openshift get output without some metadata

Tags: openshift

When i launch this command:

```
oc get all -o yaml
```

it creates a yaml that includes metadata.

Is there a possible way to exclude the metadata from the yaml output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a tool like [yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) to remove certain fields from an output:

```
oc get all -o yaml | yq 'del(.items[].metadata)'
```

Alternatively, you can use JSON and use `jq` to remove the fields with the same options:

```
oc get all -o json | jq 'del(.items[].metadata)'
```

However, `metadata` contains required fields such as `name`, so I am not sure why you would want to remove the complete `metadata` field. Potentially you'll want to remove only certain sub-fields from the output?

Comment: Thank you so much, I have to do a backup of some namespaces and I want to export the resources. So your answer is very useful. Now I'm able to take only the resources I need.